# Is it possible to modify @SpringBootTest.webEnvironment at runtime?

Tags: spring-boot-test

I would like to flip `@SpringBootTest.webEnvironment` NONE <-> RANDOM_PORT.

When I want to test the ad-hoc started application, I need RANDOM_PORT.

When I want to test remote, live applications, I need NONE.

Example: I have a typical Spring Boot test

```
url: http://localhost:${local.server.port}

@Value("${url}") private String url;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT){
...

  @Test
  void test() {
    RestAssured
      .given()
      .when()
        .get(url)
      .then()
        .statusCode(200);
}
```

It works OK.

I also want to execute the test against some other, live application. If I set
`url: http://live.app.com` then the other application is successfully tested.

However, when I test `live.app.com`, the Test Framework starts the application locally. It is unnecessary overhead.

I would like to have the same test, which depending on configurations may

- Start the application locally and verify the application
- Do not start a local application and verify the remote, live application

How to do it?